# Render Mustache template without <view> with command line

Tags: mustache

I can render Mustache template that uses partials with command line like this:

```
mustache -p partial.mustache dataView.json myTemplate.mustache
```

I don't need `dataView.json`, so I created this file which has literally two characters in it: `{}`.

This looks cumbersome. Is there a way that I can render this template in more elegant way without creating that `json` file which basically I don't need?